# How do you discover a TCPListener Service's IPaddress?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcplistener

When sending messages to a TcpListener service from another machine on the LAN, you need to know the servers ip address and port. The port is most likely already known because you probably selected it but if the IP address can vary, is there some way you can discover the ip address.

It seems to me that you need to make this info available to a sender via another method altogether.

Comment: I think this is a general socket and network programming question. Not really specific to C# or TCPListener

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 5):

One way to accomplish this is to use UDP multicast.

Basically, you have all your applications listen on a well-known (pre-determined of course) multicast IP and port. Each host then broadcasts to this address and includes their TCP IP and port for making the TCP connection in the message body. If its a game lobby system, you can also include information like the number of total players, how many are needed, etc.

Note that you control the frequency of the broadcast, when I did this a poll interval of 1000ms proved sufficient, but you can set it to whatever you want (based on your LAN rates, size of packets, etc.)

UdpClient.JoinMulticastGroup on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekd1t784%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

One more thing you should know, the multicast IP range is:

> The multicast address range is 224.0.0.0 to 239.255.255.255.

[Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/ekd1t784%28v=vs.96%29.aspx)

For some reason that information isn't super easy to find :)

Comment: Thanks. This has proved invaluable knowledge to me and assists greatly.

Comment: No problem, I added the acceptable UDP multicast range since it takes some googling to find it. Let me know if there is anything else I can do to help!

Comment: Yeah this is a solid answer. Been doing low level socket work for months and never knew this existed. Nice! :)

Comment: Thanks @BradleyDotNET. Know a bit about multicasting but never used it. I will try this one. Have you come across or heard any issues about network infrastructure restrictions for multicast?

Comment: @MaxwellTroyMiltonKing, a wireless router I was on once wouldn't allow me to open the UDP socket, so I imagine that there are some restrictions. You also have to stay in the posted IP range. I am not aware of any other issues, but I apologize about not being an expert on the IT side of this technology :(. Might be a good question for ServerFault!

Comment: It seems to be working on the network I need it to work. I guess you can't beat a simple prototype or trial and error sometimes.

Comment: @MaxwellTroyMiltonKing, Glad you were able to get it working! It worked fine on a different WAP and my switch at home, so I'm guessing it will work *most* of the time.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing magical about TCPListener to achieve this. You need to provide a mechanism to pass that information to the clients. A few ways I can think of:

- Use DNS or a directory service (e.g. LDAP or Active Directory)
- Use a registry service (i.e. your server registers itself with a server, maybe refreshing every so often, then clients retrieves server address from there)
- Server responds to any clients broadcast request (somewhat similar to ARP)

I have a similar project and using the registry and heartbeat service as a solution which is working quite well. You can use something like Zookeeper or Redis (or some other lightweigh data store) to keep the registrations or of course write your own if you feel like it.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is correct but is the answer that I thought of as well initially. I discarded that path because I need to avoid having a client needing to know the whereabouts of the required data. The trick is that I also use discovery in a wcf service hosted on the same machine that the tcplistener is on so I ended up using discovery to capture the ip address.

Comment: This is interesting. I still think registry kind of service could be useful since you can store more meta data on it; BradleyDotNETs answer gave me the idea of an hybrid approach where client and server using the multicast to find the registry service.