# Broadcast to 255 does not work, UDP broadcast to calculated broadcast address causes crash

Tags: c#, udp

I am trying to get dynamic server detection working. My code works when I use IpAddress.Broadcast (which is 255.255.255.255) with both the server and client on my computer. But when I move one of those components to an other computer, the broadcast address 255.255.255.255 does not work anymore (I do not get any results anymore).

I have calculated the broadcast address for my network, using a subnet calculator. 
The Broadcast address is: x.x.x.191. 
The other computer's IP is: x.x.x.119

When I use the direct IP, it does work. When I use the calculated broadcast IP, my program crashes (Error message: remote host refused connection).

Client code:

```
            var Client = new UdpClient();
            var RequestData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Request ParkXManagementSystem IP");
            var ServerEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

            Client.EnableBroadcast = true;
            while (serverFound == false)
            {
                //Client.Send(RequestData, RequestData.Length, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 8888)); //Broadcast to 255.255.255.255

                IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("x.x.x.191"); //Broadcast adres
                //IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("x.x.x.119"); // direct adres
                Client.Send(RequestData, RequestData.Length, new IPEndPoint(address, 8888));                    

                var ServerResponseData = Client.Receive(ref ServerEp);
                var ServerResponse = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ServerResponseData);

                if (ServerResponse.ToString().ToLower().Contains("parkxmanagement"))
                {
                    //Server is found!
                    serverFound = true;
                    //Enable button to login
                    mUiContext.Post(UpdateGUI, BTTN_LogIn);
                    Properties.Settings.Default.parkXManagementSystemIP = ServerEp.Address.ToString();
                    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                    Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
                }
            }
```

I already have a library to dynamically calculate the broadcast address, but for testing purposes, I have hardcoded it here.

My guess is that it crashes because I have bound the IP endpoint to the broadcast address, but the address that returns is not the broadcast address.
So I am thinking that I need to make an endpoint for every address in my subnet??

Comment: I think you should use multicast instead (for server discovery type of stuff). AFAIK broadcast is constrained with physical network topology.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Check this answer on how to use UDP Mulicast http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23483495/how-do-you-discover-a-tcplistener-services-ipaddress/23483528#23483528

Comment: **1.** your program should not crash just because there was a network error. Catch and report that exception in some appropriate way. **2.** What is your subnet mask? Why do you think that `x.x.x.191` is an appropriate broadcast address? That address implies a subnet of `255.255.255.40`, but `x.x.x.119` wouldn't be a valid IP address in that subnet. More typical would be a broadcast address of `x.x.x.255`. The special address `255.255.255.255` will work only on the local subnet; it should work fine if the two computers are on the same subnet.

Comment: I used a subnet calculator to calculate the address. For security reasons I will not post the full address here, but trust me, I know for sure this is the correct broadcast address ;-)
I do not want to catch the exception for every address that replies back to me that the host refused a connection. Like I said, it crashes because I think the broadcast address is different than the hosts that are replying to me (the hosts replying to me do not use the broadcast address as their local ip address ofc.)